# Replace substring in a particular postion

Tags: java

```
String date = "2012-11-28 12:30:30";
```

I want to replace the date to `2012-11-28 12:00:00` by using `String.replace` method as:

```
String replacedDate = date.replace(date.substring(14, 19), "00:00");
```

It is working fine but if date is:

```
String date = "2012-11-28 18:18:18";
```

Using the above method the result will be `2012-11-28 00:00:28` but I want the output to be `2012-11-28 18:00:00` instead.

Comment: How about parsing the string as a date, doing your stuff on the date object and transforming it back to a string?

Comment: @KARASZIIstván I didn't see your edit when I submitted mine!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the `String.replace` method here. If you know the exact indices that you wish to replace and you are sure that they will always be the same then you can use substring and string concatenation:

```
String date = "2012-11-28 12:30:30";
date = date.substring(0, 14) + "00:00";
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/0vpJKu)

Note: if your string is really represents a date, consider using a variable of type `Date` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a Date parser that ignores the minutes and seconds instead of manipulating the string directly:

```
String s = "2012-11-28 12:30:30";
//skip the minutes, seconds
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH").parse(s); 

String result = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
System.out.println("result = " + result);
```

Bonus: if the date is not in the expected format you will get a useful exception

Answer (score 1):

It's a date/time. *Treat it as such* by parsing the above into a suitable date/time object and manipulating it using date/time-related methods. That way you don't have to rely on substrig/regexps etc. and you won't run the risk of creating an invalid date/time reference.

e.g. use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), or [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for a more intuitive and robust API.

Currently you have a *stringly*-typed system, not a *strongly*-typed system.

Answer (score 0):

You could also ask for the first first ':' and add the "00:00" then

```
String date="2012-11-28 18:18:18";
int i = date.indexOf(':');
String format = date.substring(0,i+1) + "00:00";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution doesn't work because the replace method has this signature

```
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
```

not

```
public String replace(String oldChar, String newChar)
```

This answer is meant at understanding the problem, to solve it, consider the other great answers!